# Javascript - Find duplicates in an array

Tags: javascript

I want to find duplicates in a particular array, for that I have the following:

```
    this.drivers.filter((driver)=>{
      if(driver.userId == driverId){
      //this is used to updates the user location in real-time (lat, long), that's why I am removing the old location and pushing the new location
      this.removeDriver(driver.userId)
      this.pushNewDriver(lat, long, driverId);
}
else{
   //if the driver does not exists already in the array, then push it
        this.pushNewDriver(lat, long, driverId);
}
})



removeDriver(userId){
      this.drivers = this.drivers.filter((user) => {
      return user.userId !== userId;
    });
}

 pushNewDriver(lat, long, userId) {
let currentLontLat = { "lat": lat, "long": long };

 this.drivers.push({ "userId": userId, "currentLocation": currentLontLat });

}
```

What I want to do more specifically, is to update the info of a particular driver (e.g driver with Id : **sajk2299o**) however, with the code above, sometimes it works as expected (remove the driver from the array and push its new location) and sometimes it doesn't remove the old location and adds automatically the new location (somehow it does not respect `driver.userId == driverId` and go to `else` directly).

I believe that I am missing something here, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to find duplicate values in a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array)

Comment: can I see the removeDriver and pushNewDriver methods?

Comment: @banzomaikaka I've added it

Comment: Your removeDriver() function doesn't have any arguments

Comment: modified, just a typo mistake

Comment: Does this make any sense: https://jsfiddle.net/r6pzftsw/1/ ?

Comment: @banzomaikaka nope, mostly, the condition `driver.userId == driverId` does not always meet that's why it goes to `else` and it pushes a new element in the array